# Recurring Bitcoin or Altcoin Payments as a Service?

Tags: altcoin, services, recurring-payments

I was wondering are there any recurring payment services aside from the obvious coinbase one out there. I want to be able to have a finer grain control. Say I wanted to send X amount of btc/altcoins to an address every 1week until it reaches a total of # of btc/altcoins or USD value.

Comment: closely related: [Who provides Bitcoin recurring payments API?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37072/5406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question and I do not know of any especially in the altcoin spaces.  You basically have two choices to accomplish recurring payments in terms of who holds the keys.

If you are cool with a custodian of your funds, then it's a pretty easy implementation on the service provider side, but its up to the service to provide the level of control you need.  Also, if their framework is buggy, attacked, since they hold your keys, you could loose your funds without any knowledge of it happening.

The other option in a non-custodial service but the best experience you'll get would be a notification to send the transaction because you are the person holding onto the private keys and the service can't do it without you signing a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this but couldn't you run a manual transaction script that runs like a chron script weekly with a wallet and a preset amount of addresses?  it would have to keep its own internal balance and from there would have to calculate the balance.  I guess that answered your question - there is currently no out the box wallet or service that does this.